# How to write trigger to textbox IskeyboardFocused property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to change other UI element visibility when textbox is focused. I think that isKeyboardFocused event may solve my problem. So i write my xaml as following.

```
                <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <e:PropertyChangedTrigger>
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <e:ConditionBehavior>
                                    <e:ConditionalExpression>
                                        <e:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding SearchBox.IsKeyboardFocused}" Operator="Equal" RightOperand="rue" />
                                    </e:ConditionalExpression>
                                </e:ConditionBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <e:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="SearchLabel" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </e:PropertyChangedTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock x:Name="SearchLabel" Text="Search" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Visible" />
```

This trigger is not working and i could'nt find the problem. What can i do to fix this problem or any other idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bind the `Visibility` to the `IsKeyboardFocused` property as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <YourNamespace:BoolToVisConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" />
<Label Visibility="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=IsKeyboardFocused, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, ConverterParameter='invert'}">hello</Label>
```

using a customized `BoolToVisibilityConverter`:

```
public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool)) throw new ArgumentException("bool value expected");

        Visibility invisibleMode = (parameter == null || !(parameter is string) ||
                                    !((string) parameter).ToLower().Contains("hidden"))
                                       ? Visibility.Collapsed
                                       : Visibility.Hidden;

        if ((parameter as string)?.ToLower().Contains("invert") ?? false) return (!(bool) value) ? Visibility.Visible : invisibleMode;

        return ((bool) value) ? Visibility.Visible : invisibleMode;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The `Converter` parses given `CommandParameter` string for:
 - "invert": true --> invisible, false --> visible
 - "hidden": invisble case leads to `Visibilitys.Hidden`, otherwise it's `Visibility.Collapsed`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I also find another answer which solves my problem easily. It may be also useful who has the same problem like me.

```
<TextBox>
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <Style.Resources>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Label Content="Search" Foreground="LightGray" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with your question! There is no context to your problem of setting another controls property depending on a value of the TextBox. Marking this as right answer couldn't be right.

Comment: My needing was using a search label inside a textbox to prompt the user. and when it is focused to disable it's visibility. This solution is working fine also. So i decided to use this answer.

Comment: The question and title you asked (I am trying to change other UI element visibility when textbox is focused.) upon has nothing to do with this answer! For others reading this question and having the same problem to trigger across controls they won't fix it with this! Therefore it can't be the best answer to the question!

Comment: @WPFGermany ok then i tag your answer as solution. Because your answer is more appropriate to question even my solution answer is working for my case.